# Django searching empty value, validation

Tags: django, validation, search

i am creating a search app where a user can look for ingredients by writting some in search field. But when there is empty field, so there is no input q=, i would like to that he would get information that the input is required and keep him on this website. I do not know how to write it correcly for now i have written only if query == '': , but this is not what i need.

Here is my views:

```
def drink_list(request):
    template = "drinks/drink_list.html"
    return render(request, template)

def search_results(besos):

    query = besos.GET.get('q')
    if query == "":
        y = "please put input"
        return render(besos, y)

    else:
        q = Q()
        for queries in query.split():
            q |= (Q(ingredients__ingredient_name__icontains=queries))
            #why it look for 'sok z cytryny' and show as well sok z limonki
        results = Recipe.objects.filter(q)
        template = "drinks/search_results.html"
        context = {
        'results' : results,
        }
        return render(besos, template, context)
```

my template:

```
{% if results %}
  {% for drink in results %}
    <div>
      <p>{{ drink.recipe_name }}</p>
      <p>Preparation: {{ drink.preparation }}</p>
      <p>Ingredients:
        {% for ingredient in drink.ingredients.all %}
          {{ingredient.ingredient_name}}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </p>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  <div>Such ingredients do not exist</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would be using Django's
[Message Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/)

```
 if not query or query == "":
    messages.error(request, "Please put input")
    return redirect("Your Template")
```

Then in your template:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/) and fields validation, [for example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#required)